# Service worker - devtools

Tags: javascript, service, offline, worker

I want to cache a website, or at least some pages, to be offline available.

If tried with a service worker. The code is

/js/main.js

```
// Make sure sw are supported

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('../sw_cached_pages.js')
      .then((reg) => console.log('Service Worker: Registered'))
      .catch((err) => console.error(`Service Worker: Error: ${err}`)); // Cambié `console.log` a `console.error` y arreglé la comilla en `err`
  });
}
```

../sw_cached_pages.js

```
const cacheName = 'v1';

const cacheAssets = [
  'https://www.senderosdigitales.org/ruta-del-agua-lascuarre',
  'https://www.senderosdigitales.org/ruta-del-agua-lascuarre/qr1',
  'https://www.senderosdigitales.org/ruta-del-agua-lascuarre/qr2',
  'https://www.senderosdigitales.org/ruta-del-agua-lascuarre/qr3',
  'https://www.senderosdigitales.org/ruta-del-agua-lascuarre/qr4',
  'https://www.senderosdigitales.org/ruta-del-agua-lascuarre/qr5',
  'https://www.senderosdigitales.org/ruta-del-agua-lascuarre/qr6'
];

// Call Install Event

self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Installed');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
      console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files');
      return cache.addAll(cacheAssets); // Changed cache.addAll(cacheAssets) from cache.addAll(cacheAssets);
    }).then(() => self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

// Call Activate Event

self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Activated');

  // Remove unwanted caches
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cache) => {
          if (cache !== cacheName) {
            console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache');
            return caches.delete(cache);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

// Call Fetch Event

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
  e.respondWith(
    fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request))
  );
});
```

The service workers doesn´seem to be working,

there is no way to make it work.

Any idea?

I want to get the website offline available.

Comment: are you sure this path exists in production code `'../sw_cached_pages.js'`?
Also, have you added a manifest file for the worker (like described here https://web.dev/articles/add-manifest)?